# How to debug out of memory error(java heap space) causing at web logic server startup

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, weblogic, heap-memory

I am getting out of memory ,java heap space issue while starting the web logic server. below are the details about the setup.

> server memory allocation(weblogic_startup.xml) : xms=512m and xmx=512m
>
> Archive Size(.ear) :456MB (file)
>
> it is windows 64 bit machine with 4GB Ram.space ocupied by other process is up to 1.74Gb (before server start).

click here for machine memory uses detail-> https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQZxk.png

how to debug above issue, and do the cleanup ?

Comment: Change xmx to a higher value (1024m) and try again. If problem persists you have a memory leak somewhere in you app maybe.

Comment: @FranMontero , I does that ,but issue have not solved. Every thing working fine before , the issue coming recently.

Comment: Change it to 2G or however much you need to get it running, then profile your application.

Comment: @Kayaman I said, previously same was working fine,now it is creating an issue. i can not increase xms or xmx to 2 GB, because out of 4 GB ram only 1.30 Gb memory is available .

Comment: Have you tried increasing Xmx to 2G? Tell me what happens when you try that.

Comment: @Kayaman , i have done that, the whole machine is hanged beacuse windows machine ran out of memory and server throws the out of memory error.  Have you seen the attachment which is linked with my question?

Comment: Well, I suggest you solve your problem by buying more memory or freeing up enough memory to run your app.

Comment: Exactly when in the startup process does the OOM error appear in the logs? What is the message? It sounds like something outside of WebLogic might be using more memory than before and now WebLogic can't get the same amount of free memory that it did before.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a Heap Dump when OOM is reach, then analyze it with Eclipse MAT.
https://eclipse.org/mat/

JDK 1.6 has the following parameters to take a heap dump when OOM:

-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp